# Understanding "ip route" command

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, routing, iproute2

I'm trying to set up a backup route for my network as a safety net when the primary link fails; by adjusting the administrative distance with the `ip route` command. I have one router (cisco 1900 series) and two modems. My issue is i don't really understand how to set the parameters for this command. I've learnt the commands i'll use for this are:

**For primary network (use default route)**

```
ip route <network> <subnet> <ip address of main ISP modem>
```

**For back up network (set admin distance)**

```
ip route <network> <subnet> <ip address of backup ISP modem> 100
```

So my question: Is the **network** parameter supposed to be the IP address of the router? and the **ip address** parameter (which comes after subnet) the IP of the modem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes.

In long, the command of **For primary network (use default route)** is adding the default route to the highest priority in the routing table. So every traffic will route on that route.

And the second command **For back up network (set admin distance)** is adding a route with AD 100, assume you only have this two route on the routing table, basically this route will never have traffic unless you modify the **For primary network (use default route)** AD to 101 or larger.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So you're saying if my router has an ip of **192.168.1.1** i would use this for the network parameter and not **192.168.1.0**?

Comment: the usage of `ip route` is `ip route [unknown network] [which device should l look for]`, assume your **ip address of main ISP modem** is 123.123.123.123 and your **ip address of backup ISP modem** is 234.234.234.234, so **For primary network** `ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 123.123.123.123` and for **For back up network** is `ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 234.234.234.234 100`